# Twig "asset" not working after adding custom filter, Symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony, filter, twig

After adding a custom filter I get Twig Syntax Errors like:
"The function "asset" does not exist in "TwigBundle:Exception:exception_full.html.twig" at line 4".

My Extension:

```
<?php

namespace AlexanderBuerkle\ShopBundle\Twig;

use AlexanderBuerkle\ShopBundle\Twig\Extension;
use Twig_Extension;


class UnescapeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('unescape', array($this, 'unescape'));
    }

    public function unescape($value)
    {
        return html_entity_decode($value);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'unescape_extension';
    }
}
?>
```

I call the service in my config.yml (because my predecessor did so, too):

```
# Twig Extensions
services:
    ShopBundle.twig.unescape_extension:
        class: AlexanderBuerkle\ShopBundle\Twig\UnescapeExtension
        tags:
                - { name: twig.extension }
```

Why are my Twig functions overwritten? Oviously I am missing something...
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you tried clearing the cache? Usually that the culprit with new extensions.

Comment: @nakashu: when i try to clear the cache, i get a  "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Symfony/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php on line 1204"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was that the filters could not be loaded in vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php, because `getFilters()` did not return an array. Working function:

```
public function getFilters()
    {
        return array
        (
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('unescape', array($this, 'unescape')),
        );
    }
```